# Node Cheerio returns null

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying webscraping but I'm having some trouble. The body has multiple divs with a class named `.details`. I'm trying to get the HTML inside those divs.

My code is down below but it logs `null` in the console. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var url = "https://www.funko.com/products/all/categories/the-vault";
request(url, function(err, response, html) {
  if (!err && response.statusCode == 200){
    let $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const tag = $('.details');
    console.log(tag.html());

    $('.details').each((i,element)=>{
      console.log(element);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with you code. The website you're trying to scrape requests a lot of it's information via AJAX requests, so the initial `https://www.funko.com/products/all/categories/the-vault` won't return you the content you're looking for.

If you add `console.log(html)` to your script you'll see a very slimmed down version of what you're expecting because the AJAX requests haven't run yet.

Answer (score 0):

As sketchthat noted, cheerio won't help you much here.

To obtain the items data, you need to get the `collection_id` first:

```
$ curl -s 'https://www.funko.com/ui-api/cms/tables/collections/rows' | json -a data | json -c 'this.handle=="the-vault"' -a collection_id
199936515
```

then using the id, you may fetch the requied json data:

```
$ curl -s 'https://www.funko.com/ui-api/search?page=1&limit=15&&collectionId=199936515' | json 'products[0]'
{
  "id": "10883713155",
  "title": "Pop! Marvel: Phoenix/Jean Grey",
  "handle": "pop-marvel-phoenix-jean-grey",
  "product_type": "Pop!",
  "tags": "The Vault",
  "image": {
    "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0552/1401/products/Green_Phoenix_POP_CMYK_GLAM_grande_bd258ee0-0064-4573-ace4-111e01437590.jpg?v=1505506339"
  },
  "variants": [
    {
      "sku": "VAULTED"
    }
  ]
}
```

(the examples assume you have installed the 'json' cli util via `npm -g i json`)